# Applying a texture to a model as it shows up in a game

Tags: texturing

Firstly, please forgive me, I haven't used blender before but I think it may help achieve this.
I am making a 'skin' for a ship in the game 'Warthunder', as it is a historically based skin I would like it to be accurate, however, the modeller of the ship has mirrored two sides of the hull and many other parts of the ship, hence making accuracy impossible. When downloading skin files the game provides two albedo textures- one is a typical map, with UVs and includes the mirrored parts of the model. The other (apologies I don't know of an official term for it, the skinning community calls it the 'generic' map) is a texture that wraps around the model, but is not defined by the UVs and therefore has no mirrored parts. Hence, if the 'skinner' is able to, they can paint onto the usually mirrored parts but on this 'generic' map and overcome mirroring.
It should be simple, but as you can see in the photo, the 'generic' texture (the one I put the UV checker on) is severely warped and in places scaled differently (see the superstructure vs the hull). This makes it impossible to paint accurately onto without painting directly onto a 3d  model which has the texture in the same place.

Essentially, I am trying to add the generic texture to the model in Blender, but when on the model, it has to have the same warping and scaling as it does in the game. Is this possible in blender? And if not does anyone know of software in which it may be? Thanks, I understand I've probably done a poor job of explaining this so if you have any questions please ask!

[image: In the ingame image, I have already painted the unmirrored parts on the albedo file, the UV checker represents the Generic map, and I use it to show the degree of warping and mismatch in scale between various parts of the model]

Comment: "*but when on the model, it has to have the same warping and scaling as it does in the game*" Either use the correct 'generic map' UV layer that should already come with the imported model by default, or create a new one in Blender and export it with the model.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't have a UV map. It just wraps around the model like a smart material.